# Linux promises more memory than it can give

Tags: c++, linux, memory-management

Consider the following little program running on Linux:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstring>

int main() {
  size_t array_size = 10ull * 1000 * 1000 * 1000;
  size_t number_of_arrays = 20;
  char* large_arrays[number_of_arrays];

  // allocate more memory than the system can give
  for (size_t i = 0; i < number_of_arrays; i++)
    large_arrays[i] = new char[array_size];

  // amount of free memory didn't actually change
  sleep(10);

  // write on that memory, so it is actually used
  for (size_t i = 0; i < number_of_arrays; i++)
    memset(large_arrays[i], 0, array_size);

  sleep(10);

  for (size_t i = 0; i < number_of_arrays; i++)
    delete [] large_arrays[i];

  return 0;
}
```

It allocates a lots of memory, more than the system can give. However, if I monitor the memory usage with `top`, it actually doesn't decrease. The program waits a bit, then it starts to write to the allocated memory and only then the amount of available free memory drops... until the system becomes unresponsive and the program is killed by `oom-killer`.

My questions are:

- Why Linux promises to allocate more memory than it actually can provide? Shouldn't `new[]` throw a `std::bad_alloc` at some point?
- How can I make sure, that Linux actually *takes* a piece of memory without having to write to it? I am writing some benchmarks where I would like to allocate lots of memory **fast**, but at the same time, I need to stay below certain memory limit.
- Is it possible to monitor the amount of this "promised" memory?

The kernel version is `3.10.0-514.21.1.el7.x86_64`. Maybe it behaves differently on newer versions?

Comment: `char* large_arrays[number_of_arrays];` -- This is not valid C++.

Comment: Is this something that only g++ can understand? It does compile it.

Comment: @knopers8 Yes, Variable Length Arrays are GCC extension to C++ (they are a feature in C). However, you could easily make it valid per standard by making `number_of_arrays` `const` (or `constexpr`)

Comment: @knopers8 By using an extension such as VLA's, which is implemented in whatever way the compiler wants to implement them, you need to change to valid C++ and rerun your tests.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out! I don't use it in my tests though, that was just a minimal example to illustrate the problem.

Comment: The reason Linux has this behavior is because many processes ask for far more memory than they actually use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why Linux promises to allocate more memory than it actually can provide?

Because that is how your system had been configured. You can change the behaviour with. `sysctl 'vm.overcommit_memory'`.

> Shouldn't new[] throw a std::bad_alloc at some point?

Not if the system over commits the memory.

> How can I make sure, that Linux actually takes a piece of memory without having to write to it?

You can't as far as I know. Linux maps memory upon page fault when unmapped memory is accessed.

> Is it possible to monitor the amount of this "promised" memory?

I think that "virtual" size of the process memory is what you're looking for.